# Heroku CLI unresponsive on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: heroku, ubuntu-16.04, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

I'm trying to get heroku cli installed on Ubuntu 16.04, following the documentation here: [Heroku CLI Documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install) and while my system appears to install it correctly, whenever I try any Heroku commands like  heroku login the terminal hangs, and becomes unresponsive. I'm not getting any error codes.

Here's what I've tried:

I've tried installing heroku via the following methods:

```
wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

That didn't work, I uninstalled and tried this:

```
sudo snap install heroku --classic
```

That did't work, I uninstalled and tried this:

```
wget https://cli-assets.heroku.com/heroku-cli/channels/stable/heroku-cli-linux-x64.tar.gz -O heroku.tar.gz
tar -xvzf heroku.tar.gz
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin
mv heroku-cli-v6.16.12-04b3626-linux-x64 /usr/local/lib/heroku
ln -s /usr/local/lib/heroku/bin/heroku /usr/local/bin/heroku
```

And got the same result.

The one command that does seem to work is `heroku --version`, but only after about 3 minutes does it return `heroku-cli/6.16.12-04b3626 (linux-x64) node-v9.11.1`
. I don't know if there is something going on with my os, but everything else on my system seems to be working fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was my ~/.netrc file. I had somehow gotten the same entry into it over 12,000 times. After clearing that file heroku works.

Comment: Just for additional clarification (in bash): $ `rm ~/.netrc`