# Heroku-cli freezing on my computer

Tags: macos, heroku, terminal, installation, heroku-cli

Note: before you ask, no, it's not this: [Heroku CLI Unresponsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356149/heroku-cli-unresponsive); it hangs for MUCH longer than two minutes.

I'm on a Mac, and after installing Heroku onto my computer (both by `brew` and directly from the site), for any Heroku command, so long as it begins with `heroku`, it hangs forever. I've waited over ten hours at one point, and it was still hanging. I'm now pushing through Git, but it's incredibly frustrating because I can't directly make big changes to the database.

So far, I've reinstalled this program many times, installing with `brew` and direct download from the site. I've uninstalled with `brew` and by combing through all my hidden files, deleting anything that says "heroku", and trying again. Nothing has worked.

Comment: Have you tried the npm package? Might work better. Also maybe check your router and/or any firewall you may have in your network

Comment: @CliveMakamara Yes, I've tried it with npm before. Tried it again just now. Still hangs for over two minutes on everything.

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49779100/heroku-cli-unresponsive-on-ubuntu-16-04 fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks, @itajenglish. Your answer worked great!

Comment: @StevenChoi Awesome. I was banging my head at work today trying to figure out what was causing it hahaha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, @itajenglish, for the link to: [Heroku CLI unresponsive on Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49779100/heroku-cli-unresponsive-on-ubuntu-16-04)! Deleting my `~/.netrc` worked great.